# Pegar valor de um input type='text' React

Tags: javascript, react

Estou tentando resgatar o valor de um input type text.

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```js
class CreationGroups extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.handleChange();
    this.handleSubmit();
    console.log('alguma coisa');
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert(`Um nome foi enviado: ${this.state.value}`);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="component">
        <form>
          <div className="group">
            <input
              id="nameGroup"
              type="text"
              maxLength="30"
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              required
            />
            <i className="icon2" />
            <span className="bar" />
            <label id="name">
              <span className="lang" key="Text41">
                Group Name:
              </span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>

        <button id="saveGroup" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <span>Create group</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CreationGroups />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Já dei uma olhada na [documentação](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) e aparentemente está de acordo.

Porém esta me retornando o seguinte erro:

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
> ```

Comment: O problema só acontece quando você clica no botão, certo? Isso por que você está chamando o método `handleChange` sem passar nenhum argumento – que é necessário. Tente mudar o código do seu `handleClick`...

Comment: De acordo com o seu código, não se faz necessário chamar o handleChange ao executar o handleClick. O handleChange é chamado quando você atualiza o input text, e guarda o seu conteúdo no state. Ao clicar, basta executar o handleSubmit

Comment: Olá @Bins, fiz o que me indicou, porém continuo com o erro
TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSubmit' of undefined

Comment: Olá @LuizFelipe tentei fazer a mudança que me falou porem estou recebendo o seguinte erro: TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSubmit' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu componente faz duas ações (separadas):
1) atualiza o texto do input;
2) envia este texto pro alert.

Sendo assim, você deve remover this.handleChange() do método handleSubmit.
Exemplo funcionando:

https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-mclean-5z2h6